# Scrape content only inside H2 - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this markup.

```
<h2>
  Virtual Office packages
  <span>From</span><span class="cost">$74.97</span>
</h2>
```

and sometimes

```
<h2>Virtual Office packages</h2>
```

and this code.

```
service_header = service.select("h2")[0].string
```

I only want to get `Virtual Office packages` not the price info.

I can get that in second case but I get `None` if the HTML is found like the first one, having price info.

To be precise, How do I get only "**Virtual Office packages**" with either type of thos HTMLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<h2>
  Virtual Office packages
  <span>From</span><span class="cost">$74.97</span>
</h2>""")


print(soup.find("h2").next_element.strip())
Virtual Office packages


soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<h2>Virtual Office packages</h2>
""")


print(soup.find("h2").next_element)

Virtual Office packages

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<h2>
  Virtual Office packages
  <span>From</span><span class="cost">$74.97</span>
</h2>""")


print(soup.find("h2").contents[0].strip())
Virtual Office packages

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<h2>Virtual Office packages</h2>
""")

print soup.find("h2").contents[0]
Virtual Office packages
```